# OAuts with Signpost - how to sign POST to get Access token

Tags: post, oauth, signpost, auth-token

I'm working with client who provided me with somewhat vague
instructions. Here's what I'm doing (using `CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer` as
consumer and `DefaultOAuthProvider` as provider)

1. I'm able to get response token from doing this:

   ```
   String requestToken = provider.retrieveRequestToken
   (OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);
   ```

   this is in form of URL with params so I'm parsing the actual token
   out for example:
   `https://foobar.com/oauth/login_authorize?oauth_token=XRFCGPbES3M2bYZy...`
2. Now - the instructions that I get say:
   `Given the request token obtained in step 1, login with the user’s
   credentials (name and password) as POST parameters and sign the
   request with the request token/secret
   POST https://foobar.com/oauth/login_authorize`

That's where I'm having difficulties. Obviously I have to input that
requestToken somewhere so I do this (`post` is HttpPost that contains user credentials):

```
consumer.setTokenWithSecret(requestToken, SECRET);
consumer.sign(post);
```

It doesn't work. It actually generates 200 status but what I get is a
generic error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`retrieveRequestToken` does not return a request token, it returns an authenticationUrl that you need to send your users to so they can sign in. Request token is saved in provider object.

```
String authenticationUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken( call_back_url )
```

Note: According to the oauth standard the users sign in on the providers site with their credentials. After they have done that you (as a consumer) can get the Access Token and after that you can access their data on the providers site.

```
// After user has signed in
provider.retrieveAccessToken(null)

// access token is saved in provider and provider knows which consumer uses it
// so now you can sign with your consumer and connect with the request
URL url = new URL( protected_resources_url )
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
consumer.sign(request)
request.connect()
```

If you have the user credentials you can do the authorization in your script

```
// Using grails and functional-tests
get(authenticationUrl)
// Image the site shows a simple form with username/password and a login button
setRedirectEnabled false
form {
  username = "mario"
  password = "peach"

  click "login"
}
```

And then do `retrieveRequestToken` and the code mentioned above

Hope this helps you
// Jonas